# get all x,y points within any polygon

Tags: c++

I am trying to get all x,y within **ANY** polygon shape in c++

for e.g  I have a rectangle that has the following cordinates,

Point 1:

```
X = 5
Y = 10
```

Point 2:

```
X = 5
Y = 8
```

Point 3:

```
X = 9
Y = 8
```

Point 4:

```
X = 9
Y = 10
```

so the cordinates within polygon base on the 4 points given will be

```
X = 6 Y = 9 
X = 7 Y = 9 
X = 8 Y = 9
```

I found this from http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/

```
bool pointInPolygon() {
    int   i, j=polySides-1;
    bool  oddNodes=NO;

    for (i=0; i<polySides; i++) {
    if (polyY[i]<y && polyY[j]>=y
       ||  polyY[j]<y && polyY[i]>=y) {
         if (polyX[i]+(y-polyY[i])/(polyY[j]-polyY[i])*(polyX[j]-polyX[i])<x) {
             oddNodes=!oddNodes; }}
         j=i; 
    }
     return oddNodes; 
}
```

and even this http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html

```
int pnpoly(int nvert, float *vertx, float *verty, float testx, float testy) {
  int i, j, c = 0;
  for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
  if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) &&
   (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
     c = !c;
  }
 return c;
}
```

In fact most of my search results I found will have something similar to the codes(shown above). from what I understand, the code(shown above) will only return you a true/false if the point is within the polygon and  does not return any cords that is found within the polygon.

Comment: By *any* shape, you are including self-intersecting polygons?

Answer (score 4):

Run a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) on your polygon and record all of the points with integer coordinates as you go along.

This works for a general polygon.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function  `bool pointInPolygon(polygon *pol, int point_x, int point_y)`, you can do:

```
int x_min, x_max; // determines x min and max of your polygon
int y_min, y_max; // determines y min and max of your polygon
int i, j;

...

for(i = x_min; i < x_max; i++) {
  for(j = y_min; j < y_max; j++) {
     if(pointInPolygon(pol, i, j)) {
        // add the point (i, j) in an array
     }
  }
}
```

It works well while you work with 2D.